# Laravel single database session with different application server

Tags: mysql, laravel, session

I am storing the session of laravel in the database table sessions.
I am having a following case:

1. If I login from different Ip address can I use the same session stored in the database? (here database in different server).
   for example I have two machines Machine 1 and Machine 2 with ip address 172.XXX.XXX.001 and 172.XXX.XXX.002, if I login successfull with 172.XXX.XXX.001 then Can I access the server with the ip address 172.XXX.XXX.002?

Updated:

2.If I am login with one machine, and in the server side it has following setup,

two app servers App1 and App2 and one DB server DB

if one app server App1 is down and I am making App2 enabled. since I made the App2 enabled, In this case will I need to login again? or the app2 will work like app1

(here App1 and App2 have different IP)

or is there any possibility?

Comment: Short anwer, no. Each machine and to be more specific, each client making a request will get its own session.

Comment: I have updated the question, I need having clarification reg to the App servers and DB Server

Comment: If multiple laravel instances share the same session database you won't need to login again if one of the instances is down

Comment: But, I put the server app1 and server app2 in different IP. if the app servers which enabled with different IP will get the record of the same user?

Comment: As long as they use the same database yes, the user identifies himself with a session cookie which is saved in that database.

Comment: But this is not working with load balancer. If I use load balancer and two app servers App1 and App2 for Database server DB1 it actually logs out or says unathenticated

Comment: With loadbalancer, if I login with App server 1, and then if any of my requests passes through App server 2 then the request returns as 401 unauthenticated and viceversa. Any thoughts?